# replace "abc".equals(variable) by variable.equals("abc") in c# code

Tags: c#

I maintain a c# project and i found many `variable.Equals("abc")` which are not compliant with best practice.

How to replace at once all these comparisons by these form : `"abc".Equals(variable)`.

I use visual studio. I'm open with regex...

Thx a lot !

Comment: There's nothing at all wrong with `variable.Equals("literal")`. Depending on the types involved, automatically reversing these may even _break things_ in cases where you have types with custom `Equals()` overrides.

Comment: If variable is null, it will throw with variable.Equals("literal"), but not with "literal".Equals(variable).

Comment: assuming that `variable` is a `string` I think the best practice in C# would be `variable == "abc"`

Comment: @juharr No, MS documentation explicitly states `Avoid using the == and != operators when you test for equality` see the note at the end of [this page on string comparison](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings)

Comment: its valid but you can check [Eqauls() implementation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Note, that string (`"abc"` in your case) can be *very elaborated*, e.g. `x.Equals($"abc {(y.Equals(z) ? "P" : $"3 + {} \" + 5"),3} def")`. In general case you want *parser* (Roslyn), not *regex*.

Comment: `string.Equals(a, b)` and we are on the safe side (we can even have *both* `a` and `b` being `null`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Regex :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


namespace ConsoleApplication52
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = @"variable.equals(""abc"") variable.equals(""def"") variable.equals(""ghi"")";

            string pattern = @"(^|\s)(?'key1'[^.]+).equals\((?'key2'[^\)]+)\)";
            Regex r = new Regex(pattern);

            MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

            Program c = new Program();

            MatchEvaluator myEvaluator = new MatchEvaluator(c.ReplaceVariable);

            string results = r.Replace(input, myEvaluator);
 
        }
        public string ReplaceVariable(Match m)
        {
            return m.Groups["key2"].Value + ".equals(" + m.Groups["key1"].Value + ")"; 


        }
    }
 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`"abc".equals(variable)` makes no difference to adherance to best practices

What you should be using is `string.Equals(stringA, stringB, StringComparison.ChooseEnumHere)`

This is always the ideal way to compare strings as the `StringComparison` [enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringcomparison?view=net-7.0) allows you for finetuned control over case and culture sensitivity of the strings. Use of `==` or `strA.Equals(strB)` will *always* amount to an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison between the strings. In the name of maintainability it is best to explicitly state what you comparison rules are

I highly recommend reading this bit of [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/compare-strings) to learn about how to go about properly comparing strings

To directly answer your question, if you want to replace every instance of something with something else, you can use `CTRL+SHIFT+H`, which will allow you to search and replace in a much wider scale then just the document or selection (which is what `CTRL+H` does). Just be wary that you don't kill some text that you didn't intend to replace

Comment: This site never fails to amaze me

Comment: Just because somebody doesn't like your answer they give you negative points.  The OP accepted my answer and I still got negative points above.  the OP says "replace at once all these comparisons" and my solution is the only one that will work with multiple and variety of inputs.

Comment: @jdweng oh I fully well know how and why this happened. Still doesn't make the situation any less hilarious